# How can I manually cut existing polylines at a point of my choosing in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, line

I want to edit polylines so that only the part of the polylines that fall within a certain area are remaining. SQL queries highlight the whole polyline if it falls within the desired area and hence does not achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

1. First select all polylines you want to cut
2. then go to menu Objects and choose "Set target (ctrl+T)"
3. Now select a polygon or area
4. If you want to cut polylines which falls outside selected polygon/area choose "Objects/Erase Outside..."

   Data Disaggregation window will show up and you will have to choose method.

After that, polylines will be sliced just at points where intersection with selected polygon occurred

Comment: Do remember to make a copy of your data as you are deleting the part not within the polygon.

Comment: If the answer work for you: you can "accepted" the answer (click the grey checkmark at the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

With MapInfo Pro v2019 we added support for showing derived objects in queries instead of objects from the base table.

We introduced a new keyword that lets you specify that you want to see the derived object instead of the object from the base table. The keyword is `Object`.

You use this keyword by placing it after the expression that creates the derived spatial object in the SQL Select statement. Like this:

```
Select a.*, Buffer(a.obj, 20, 25, "m") Object
From Addresses As "a"
Into Selection
```

In the basic example above, I create a buffer around the input point dataset and using the Object keyword I specify that I want to see this derived spatial object when I show the query in a map.

Similar you can extract the part of a line that is within a polygon and show this:

```
Select r.*, c.NAME, Overlap(c.OBJ, r.OBJ) Object
From roads As "r", CityBoundaries As "c"
Where r.OBJ Intersects c.OBJ
```